# Decorate all class methods without redecorating each time

Tags: python

I have a class which instantiate a bunch of classes. I do not want each of these classes to be decorated (for testing purposes) so I wrap them in the main class with my wrapper which in turn wraps all their methods. When I create multiple instances of the class its functions are already wrapped since I use the uninstantiated object to prepare it. Is there a good way to avoid re-wrapping them every time?

Simplified examples:

**UserResource.py:**

```
class UserResource(object):
    def test(self):
        pass
```

**resource.py:**

```
def resource_wrapper(resource_class):
    def decorate(cls):
        for attr in cls.__dict__:
            if callable(getattr(cls, attr)) and not attr.startswith('_'):
                setattr(cls, attr, _function_wrapper(getattr(cls, attr)))
        return cls
    return decorate(resource_class)


def _function_wrapper(fn):
    from functools import wraps

    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]
        arg = kwargs.pop('test', False)

        print arg  # See output further down

        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

**tl;dr** A bunch of uninstantiated classes, wrapped with a wrapper that wraps all its functions. Functions gets wrapped every time it's run.

When I run this I see the following behaviour:

```
r1 = resource_wrapper(UserResource)()
r1.test(test=True)
# True

r2 = resource_wrapper(UserResource)()
r2.test(test=True)
# True
# False

r3 = resource_wrapper(UserResource)()
r3.test(test=True)
# True
# False
# False
```

Is there a way to only wrap the functions once instead of every time?

Comment: Sounds like you need a class factory. Rather than modifying `UserResource` in-place, you should write a function that returns a new class containing wrapped methods.

Comment: what do you mean by "for testing purposes"? I would probably always wrap them, and mock the wrapper out for my tests?

Comment: Ah, yes, but not only for testing purposes, I also want the class to have it's normal behaviour and if it's used in this special way other boilerplate magic is applied. It's hard to explain but remember that the code above is a pretty simplified example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing to manipulating the instantiated object instead of the class itself.

My resource_wrappers if changed to `for attr in dir(cls):` and i pass `cls` to _function_wrapper using it as `self`.

For clarity, this is the final result of the example code:

**UserResource.py:**

```
class UserResource(object):
    def test(self):
        pass
```

**resource.py:**

```
def resource_wrapper(resource_class):
    def decorate(cls):
        for attr in dir(cls):
            if callable(getattr(cls, attr)) and not attr.startswith('_'):
                setattr(cls, attr, _function_wrapper(cls, getattr(cls, attr)))
        return cls
    return decorate(resource_class)


def _function_wrapper(cls, fn):
    from functools import wraps

    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self = cls
        arg = kwargs.pop('test', False)

        print arg  # See output further down

        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

**Usage:**

```
r1 = resource_wrapper(UserResource())
r1.test(test=True)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at implementing the template pattern. This would provide you with commonalities in the header, and variations which you can implement solely in the derivates.

I can't extract more information from your question but perhaps a strategy pattern would provide a solution.

```c
/**
 * An abstract class that is common to several games in
 * which players play against the others, but only one is
 * playing at a given time.
 */

abstract class Game {
 /* Hook methods. Concrete implementation may differ in each subclass*/
    protected int playersCount;
    abstract void initializeGame();
    abstract void makePlay(int player);
    abstract boolean endOfGame();
    abstract void printWinner();

    /* A template method : */
    public final void playOneGame(int playersCount) {
        this.playersCount = playersCount;
        initializeGame();
        int j = 0;
        while (!endOfGame()) {
            makePlay(j);
            j = (j + 1) % playersCount;
        }
        printWinner();
    }
}

//Now we can extend this class in order 
//to implement actual games:

class Monopoly extends Game {

    /* Implementation of necessary concrete methods */
    void initializeGame() {
        // Initialize players
        // Initialize money
    }
    void makePlay(int player) {
        // Process one turn of player
    }
    boolean endOfGame() {
        // Return true if game is over 
        // according to Monopoly rules
    }
    void printWinner() {
        // Display who won
    }
    /* Specific declarations for the Monopoly game. */

    // ...
}

class Chess extends Game {

    /* Implementation of necessary concrete methods */
    void initializeGame() {
        // Initialize players
        // Put the pieces on the board
    }
    void makePlay(int player) {
        // Process a turn for the player
    }
    boolean endOfGame() {
        // Return true if in Checkmate or 
        // Stalemate has been reached
    }
    void printWinner() {
        // Display the winning player
    }
    /* Specific declarations for the chess game. */

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean with implementing the template pattern. Are you referring to mixins?

Comment: In the template method of this design pattern, one or more algorithm steps can be overridden by subclasses to allow differing behaviors while ensuring that the overarching algorithm is still followed.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, I guess mixins would be the most pythonesque way of implementing inheritance for this particular usecase. I wanted to avoid this and keep the resource classes (in my example) UserResource completely clean of changes and have them being manipulated only when instantiated in a specific usecase since my layer adds caching etc on external method calls.